# Getting Method post not allowed error in Instamojo

Tags: php, curl, instamojo

I am getting `Method \"POST\" not allowed` error while processing payment using Instamojo payment gateway. Don't Know what I am doing wrong here.

```
$this->load->helper('url');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://test.instamojo.com/api/1.1/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //<---- add this line or attach ssl certi
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Api-Key:test_e7ae89197569462c232b303d30e",
        "X-Auth-Token:test_a62220667c7197fc3a1ac17c1da"));
    $payload = Array(
 'purpose' => "Fifa 16",
 'amount' => "3499",
 'phone' => "990900909",
 'buyer_name' => "Ajay Singh",
 'redirect_url' => base_url().'Billing/paymentconfirmation',
 'webhook' => base_url().'Billing/paymentconfirmation',
 'send_email' => true,
 'send_sms' => true,
 'email' => "123@gmail.com",
 'allow_repeated_payments' => false
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($payload));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


echo $response;
```

Getting a response from the above code

```
{ "success": false, "message": "Method \"POST\" not allowed." }
```

Comment: Is the URL correct?

Comment: yes url is correct ! checked twice

Comment: You are not calling that method in your code, so either you've given us the wrong code, or you are using a framework that automatically uses a `post()` method when posting to a page.

Comment: using codeignitor

Comment: using codeignitor

Comment: `https://test.instamojo.com/api/1.1/` is likely not the correct URL, there should probably be an action on the end of that, like `https://test.instamojo.com/api/1.1/payment`.

Comment: Also, you probably want to revoke those keys now that you've posted them to a public forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`https://test.instamojo.com/api/1.1/` is the *base* URL for the API. You need to hit a specific endpoint. See https://docs.instamojo.com/docs/payments-api:

For example:

```
Create a Request
https://www.instamojo.com/api/1.1/payment-requests/

Creating a Refund
https://www.instamojo.com/api/1.1/refunds/
```

Comment: Can't i use it on localhost as i am getting this error now
 { "success": false, "message": { "webhook": [ "Domain name should not be \"localhost\" or \"127.0.0.1\"" ] } }

Comment: You can't pass `localhost` to a remote API as callback. The callback needs to be a live, publicly reachable URL.

Comment: What should i do now...as website is under construction

Comment: If you want your callback to work, you need to develop on a live URL.

Comment: @AjaySingh You could use service like https://ngrok.com/ to test local URLs for webhook calls.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Bingo!! Wow... this was so silly mistake made by me, but your answer solved it!! I wasted my 3 hours for this :( thanks a lot... God bless u :)